# read values from external json data file in postman

Tags: postman

In my external jsondata file, i have defined “external” : null and I am calling that attribute in my post request body as “external”:{{external}} but acutally the “null”” value is not called. In the request body the value shows as “external”:{{external}} instead of “external”: null. please help me

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9606

It looks like a issue have raised above ticket , but as a work around use the below line of code in your pre-request code:

```
data["external"]===null?pm.variables.set("external",null):undefined
```

Here we are setting the value to null explicitly to null in local variable scope